# How Can I create three new columns for my data?

Tags: python, pandas

I've got some data that looks like

```
tweet_id               worker_id    option
397921751801147392  A1DZLZE63NE1ZI  pro-vaccine
397921751801147392  A3UJO2A7THUZTV  pro-vaccine
397921751801147392  A3G00Q5JV2BE5G  pro-vaccine
558401694862942208  A1G94QON7A9K0N  other
558401694862942208  ANMWPCK7TJMZ8   other
```

What I would like is a single line for each tweet id, and three 6 columns identifying the worker id and the option.

It the desired output is something like

```
tweet_id              worker_id_1  option_1     worker_id_2    option_2     worker_id_3    option 3
397921751801147392 A1DZLZE63NE1ZI pro-vaccine A3UJO2A7THUZTV pro_vaccine A3G00Q5JV2BE5G pro_vaccine
```

How can I achieve this with pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is about reshaping data from long to wide format. You can create a grouped count column as id to spread as new column headers and then use `pivot_table()`, finally rename the columns by pasting the multi-level together.

```
df['count'] = df.groupby('tweet_id').cumcount() + 1
df1 = df.pivot_table(values = ['worker_id', 'option'], index = 'tweet_id', 
                     columns = 'count', aggfunc='sum')
df1.columns = [x + "_" + str(y) for x, y in df1.columns]
```

[image]

---

An alternative option to `pivot_table()` is `unstack()`:

```
df['count'] = df.groupby('tweet_id').cumcount() + 1
df1 = df.set_index(['tweet_id', 'count']).unstack(level = 1)
df1.columns = [x + "_" + str(y) for x, y in df1.columns]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the bit about long vs wide.  This works well, thanks